# ASP.Net MVC 3 & System.Data.Entity?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm creating my first asp.net MVC website(the version 3).

I'm using Entity Framework to get data from my database, so for now, I've a movies list in my database.

I'm trying to do a page which display the list of these movies.

So, the controller seems to be OK, it returns a View(IEnumerable).

In the view, I specified the type of my model:

@model IEnumerable

Movie is a class generated with a T4 template from my edmx, so it is heriting from EntityObject.

Now, when I try to display my page, I'm getting an error, indicating me that I've to import System.Data.Entity:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during
>   the compilation of a resource required
>   to service this request. Please review
>   the following specific error details
>   and modify your source code
>   appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0012: Le
>   type
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject'
>   est défini dans un assembly qui n'est
>   pas référencé. Vous devez ajouter une
>   référence à l'assembly
>   'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 27:      Line 28:      Line 29:
>   public class
>   _Page_Views_Movie_List_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage>
>   { Line 30:          Line 31: #line
>   hidden
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\93402ec0\8f8e48f4\App_Web_list.cshtml.9612c299.pwpwk-k5.0.cs
>   Line: 29

But, I've referenced this dll in my project and i've the corresponding using in my controller.

I tried to put this using in the cshtml:
@using System.Data.Entity but it doesn't compile with(cannot find Entity in System.Data)

So what should I do?

all my projects are .Net 4(not the client profile)

Comment: which dll did you ref - System.Data or System.Data.Entity?

Comment: For the love of all programming gods, uninstall your .NET Framework language packs for English exception messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things - 
1. change your model definition as was mentioned by Muhammed - its more standard that way as well
2. include a reference to:
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.Entity.dll

OR 
use the POCO Entity.Net templates in whatever projects your entities are in to free you from the dependency on that library in your mvc project.

Answer (score 3):

add the following line to your web.config

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Comment: I tried:     
<system.web>
   <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Adding this reference allows you to specify @using System.Data.Entity in your view, which allows you to reference entities

Answer (score 1):

For Asp.Net Mvc 2 And 3

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
 <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  ...
 </assemblies>
```

For ASP.NET MVC 4 (.NET4.5)  change from

```
<system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

To

```
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try specifying typed enumeration like

```
@model IEnumerable<MyEntityObjectType>
```